# How do I do that if you don't put anything in (IF) and press enter it will run correctly?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wat that if user doesn't enter nothing or just type anything else that is not Y or N to ask him again.

I tried may things. I am realy new on batch so i need help.
(Nothing) is the enter or anything else that you put that is not Y or N

```bat
    set /p again=Repeat again? [Y/N]= 
    if /i %again%== (Nothing) goto second
    if /i %again%== N exit
    if /i %again%== Y goto again
    :second
    set /p again=Repeat again? [Y/N]= 
    if /i %again%== (Nothing) goto second
    if /i %again%== N exit
    if /i %again%== Y goto again
```

Actualy if you just enter or type anything else that is not Y or N will ask one more time and will exit.

Comment: `if "%again%"=="" rem do stuff...`

Comment: Thanks It works with the enter. But with anything else still going wrong

Comment: Put `goto somewhere` after the `if` conditions. By the way, consider to use [`if /I`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html). And use [`exit /B`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) rather than `exit`...

Comment: I did already the /i, but what funtion has the /b at exit /b ?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `exit /?` to find out a little more about the `exit` command. But please read my answer, because you're without a doubt using the wrong command for your task.

Comment: Well, I provided a link, did you not open it??

Comment: Where is the `:again` label where the `goto` will go? I do not see one in your code. BTW, please see the answer from @Compo.

Comment: I'd assume @lit, as the code snippet provided in the question body is asking if they wish to repeat something, that the `:again` label is somewhere within the area represented by the blank line! As their code is already using a `:second` label and a `goto second`, it is assumed that they know a `:again` label is necessary when they use `goto again`.

Comment: @Compo @lit Yes the `:again` label is on the top of the code

Comment: I added goto somewhere after the if and nothing happen. It just breakes the code. Actual code: `set /p again=Repeat again? [Y/N]= if /i "%again%"=="" goto second if /i %again%== N exit if /i %again%== Y goto again`
@aschipfl

Comment: Well @PeterJan, adding it there without the commands which follow it, doesn't really help make your code look any better. You should really provide all of the missing code, or just leave it out, complete with the unnecessary and confusing `@echo off` statement, which should only really exist at the very top of your code, and we know that isn't it. Incidentally, is there a particular reason why you seem to be deliberately ignoring my three line replacement of your bottom nine lines?

Comment: @CompoI didn't ignore it, i am just new on this platform so i didn't see your comment, sorry. Now i asked something below

Comment: Well, with `goto somewhere` I meant to put `goto` after the `if` conditions but with `somewhere` replaced by an existing and functionally useful label, I thought that would be obvious, but apparently not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is because you're using the incorrect command for your task. When you use `Set /P` the end user is free to enter nothing or anything at all, *(which includes poison characters)*. The solution is to use the correct command, `Choice`, which allows only specific entries. To find out exactly how to use the `Choice` command, open a Command Prompt window and enter `choice /?`.

Here's how I may do it using the `Choice` command.

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
Choice /C yn /N /M "Attack again [Y/N]="
If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B
GoTo again
```

Comment: Okay, It works but not as I want. I am Spansih, so it dsays `Attack again [S,N]?`
(S) is Si=Yes (N) is No=No. But i want to be displayed in English and with out the `?` the ``,`` and with a `=`

Must bee like this `Attack again [Y/N]=`

@Compo

Comment: @PeterJan, my answer body told you exactly how to learn to use the `choice` command. Had you done so, you'd have clearly seen a very quick fix for that requirement. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah... Sorry I am stupid, I'm very clueless, forgive me

Comment: @PeterJan, I've modified/edited your code to correct your attempt at syntax highlighting, you should be able to view it in your own question, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no saying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the strings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"` - that is, double-quotes `'not single quotes'`

SET /P "var=Prompt" does not change `var` if <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is pressed. Consequently, if `var` is originally empty, it remains empty.

`if /i "%var%"=="value"` performs a comparison on empty variables/values or those containing separators (eg spaces) The '/i' make the comparison case-insensitive.

`IF DEFINED var` is true if `var` is **currently** defined (note: not `%var%`.)

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

In your code, the **label** `again` is undefined although the **variable** `again` may be defined (depending on user-input).

If you enter some value that is neither `y` nor `n` nor *empty* then your code will simply proceed to the next statement, so for instance if you enter `z` at the first `set/p` then execution will simply proceed through all of the `if` tests to the label `second` and execute the second `set /p` command.

For example:

```
:: Ensure the variable "again" is not defined
:RETRY1
set "again="
:: Get user-input to "again"
set /p again=Repeat again? [Y/N]= 
:: Test the value entered - ENTER only (first way)
if defined again (echo something was entered) else (echo ENTER only)
:: Test the value (second way - more conventional using /i to make case-insensitive)
if "%again%"=="" goto second
if /i "%again%"=="N" exit
if /i "%again%"=="Y" goto yes
:: We get here if the entry was neither ENTER alone, "Y" or "N"
echo "%again%" is not a valid response.
goto retry1
```

Comment: Can you write the code please? I have not 100% clear

Comment: @PeterJan, you should perhaps say what part is unclear to you, so the answerer has a chance to elaborate on that...

Comment: What is not clear to me is what i must change so it works

Comment: Easy, @PeterJan, you should change your entire script, _(instead of just the small portion of it you posted in your question)_, to use `choice` for a selection of pre known single character responses. It is clear from the code you've posted in the question that there is more code. It seems silly to fix only this portion of it, as the rest is likely to suffer from the same lack of understanding you have in receiving input and validating it.